# change button text after click w/ clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard.js

I'm using clipboard.js to copy some text on my webpage. I've go that working great but I'd like to change the button text after a user clicks to copy the text.

Here's what I have so far:
a div with the text:

```
<div #landingpage>
TEST TEXT
</div>
```

a button:

```
<button class="btn" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#landingpage" 
onclick="myFunction()">Copy Content</button>
```

and javascript:

```
<script>
(function(){
  new Clipboard('#copy-button');
})();
</script>
```

How do change button text to "Copied" after I click and then have it revert back to just "Copy" after a few seconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to the `success` event of the `clipboard` and change the text.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var $btnCopy = $('#copy-button');

  $btnCopy.on('click', function() {
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('#copy-button');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      $btnCopy.text('Copied');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $btnCopy.text('Copy');
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="landingpage"> TEST TEXT  </div>

<button class="btn" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#landingpage">Copy Content</button>
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whsr2paf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. For some reason it does not work when I add this to my website. I'm using it on a wordpress site (Divi framework). Would that change your answer?

Comment: @HanzGruber The only one I would change is `<div #landingpage>` to `<div id="landingpage">`. Maybe that might be the issue you are running into.

Comment: Thanks again. I checked that and its all correct, here's some errors from my browser console. Im not sure what is means. https://www.screencast.com/t/IGqCeGgKM, https://www.screencast.com/t/11fGzyqtV2C9

Comment: @HanzGruber Check the updated post and the fiddle. You did not define the function which is invoked on click. Instead bind it using js.