# Using Clipboard.js to change button text by a class

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I found this
[change button text after click w/ clipboard.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191594/change-button-text-after-click-w-clipboard-js)

but it causes an error: $ is not a function, see screenshot below

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/8535357?key=55d48e1db3b3e996966454c551958fac

How can I change the button text with Clipboard.js after someoen have clicked it by a **class** instead of an **ID**?

For example, the button text will be changed to 'copied' and after some time it will automatically change back to the original text.

Below is my code:

```html
<button
  class="copyElement"
  data-clipboard-text="123"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<script>new ClipboardJS('.copyElement');</script>
```

Comment: Its because you need `jQuery`...

Comment: @TechySharnav But he didn't use jQuery in his example, I do not know how to do that...Furthermore, I need to do it by a class instead of an ID

Comment: @Ace The accepted answer definitely has jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `success` event without `jQuery`

https://clipboardjs.com/#events

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyElement')

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    let oldtext = e.trigger.textContent
    e.trigger.textContent = 'Copied!'
    setTimeout(() => e.trigger.textContent = oldtext, 2000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button class="copyElement" data-clipboard-text="123">
  <span>Take Me There 1</span>
</button>

<button class="copyElement" data-clipboard-text="456">
  <span>Take Me There 2</span>
</button>
```